# release object of a return method object c

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks

in run the app with the analyze build, and Xcode found me a lot of memory leak and there is one in particular that i don't know how solve here it is:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {



UIImageView *sectionImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
if (section == 0)sectionImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];


return sectionImage;
}
```

so my question is, how i can release this sectionImage? if is the return of the method?

**EDIT:**

i have another question, analyze give me another memory leak, i have this:

.h
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath *directCellPath;

.m

@synthesize directCellPath = _directCellPath;

```
- (id)init{
if ((self = [super initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil])) {


    self.directCellPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] init];

}
return self;
}
```

then in the code i use it and finally in the dealloc i do this:

```
- (void)dealloc {

[_directCellPath release];

[super dealloc];
}
```

and give me a memory leak on this line:

```
self.directCellPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc] init];
```

why if i have deallocated it in the dealloc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must just use an autorelease like this

UIImageView *sectionImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, you released `_directCellPath`, not `directCellPath`. There is a difference.

Comment: but if i do _directCellPath don't work, if i do self.directCellPath tell me that i am no more the owner...

Answer (score 0):

you must do this

```
@synthesize directCellPath
```

and this

```
 - (void)dealloc 
{

self.directCellPath = nil;

[directCellPath release];
[super dealloc];

}
```